# How can I use sed to replace multiple characters?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have this script:

```
replace 3

echo 12345 | sed "s/^\(.\){"$1"}/\1hi/"
```

I also tried this:

```
echo 12345 | sed "s/^\(.{"$1"}\)/\1hi/"
```

In this situation I want the script to add 'hi' after the first 3 characters of '12345' (123hi45). This is a script so the '3' is an argument and can change. I'm really stuck here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command would have worked if you had escaped the curly braces (I've also quoted the `$1` that you leave unquoted for unknown reasons):

```
$ set -- 3
$ echo 12345 | sed "s/^\(.\{$1\}\)/\1hi/"
123hi45
```

The repetition modifier `{n}` is an *extended* regular expression modifier, which in a *basic* regular expression is written as `\{n\}`.  The `sed` utility is using basic regular expressions by default.

You would save a few characters by rewriting it as

```
echo 12345 | sed "s/^.\{$1\}/&hi/"
```

Personally I would have taken another approach...

---

You want to add the string `hi` after the 3rd character in `12345` where "the 3rd" is given by the value in `$1`.

```
echo 12345 | sed 's/./&hi/'"$1"
```

When `$1` is `3`, then the `sed` expression would look like

```
s/./&hi/3
```

This would replace the 3rd match of `.` (any character) with that same character (this is what `&` does in the replacement) followed by `hi`.

Putting a digit, `n`, at the end of an `s` command in `sed` like this makes `sed` substitute the `n`:th match of the pattern.

Test running (with a modified input and replacement for readability reasons):

```
$ set -- 3
$ echo abcde | sed 's/./&<hi>/'"$1"
abc<hi>de
```

```
$ set -- 4
$ echo abcde | sed 's/./&<hi>/'"$1"
abcd<hi>e
```

```
$ set -- 1
$ echo abcde | sed 's/./&<hi>/'"$1"
a<hi>bcde
```

Comment: `\{n,m\}` was added to BRE before `{n,m}` was added to ERE. As it broke backward compatibility for ERE, there are some `egrep` or `awk` implementations that still don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=$1

echo 12345 | sed -r "s/(^.{$n})/\1hi/"
```

This requires the use of the `-r` option for sed to specify extended regex (`-E` on macos).  I'm not sure how your input is going to be fed into the script though (`12345`) so I just left it as you had in your example.